# C# WinForms Нужна помощь в унификация поиска процессов

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

Доброго времени суток программисты! В данный момент я пишу программу которая проверяет запущен-ли процесс Programm*****.exe (Вместо звёздочек много разных цифр, они всегда разные) и пишет запущен-ли он или нет, как мне унифицировать поиск? Что мне надо написать вместо звёздочек что бы при каждом например запуске Programm57395.exe или Programm36754.exe мне писалось запущен процесс!

```
 if (Programm*****.exe.Length > 0)
            {
                label9.Text = "Процесс запущен";
                Timer.Enabled = true;
            }
```

Comment: `var result = Process.GetProcesses().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProcessName.StartsWith("Programm"));`

Comment: Я в C# не очень шару, куда мне это вписывать и как вставить в if?

Comment: Ну тогда не кажется вам, что работа с процессами, это еще рано для вас? А так, если для `if`, то `if (Process.GetProcesses().Any(x => x.ProcessName.StartsWith("Programm")))`

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, всё работает) Я с радостью занялся бы чем нибудь другим, но мне это нужно.